# Amazon Quicksight: is there any way to use 2 dates as X axis?

Tags: charts, amazon-quicksight

In Quicksight, I have data like this:

[image: Quicksight table]

**What I am trying to do:**

I want a chart that shows the sum of `amount` over `created_date` WITH the sum of `amount` over `resolved_date` (that second part is the challenge, the first one is easy). So it is kind of using dates as an X-axis, just that they are different date fields (`created_date` and `resolved_date`). Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: We had the exact same requirement, and I couldn't find any way to do this in the current version of QS. I used pandas to process the data further into the right form.